# How to access attribute which are stored as variables

Tags: ruby, variables

model Sample has attributes car,bike

```
x ="bike"

y = Sample.new
```

How can I do?

y.x ??
It gives me an error
Is there any way I can do it, I know that x is an attribute but I dont know which one.

So how can I get y.x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-send) to invoke a method on an object when the method is stored as a string:

```
x = "bike"

y = Sample.new

y.send(x) # Equivalent to y.bike
```

The following are equivalent, except that you may `send` protected methods:

```
object.method_name
object.send("method_name")
object.send(:method_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use dynamic message passing. Try this:

```
y.send :bike
```

Or, in your case

```
y.send x
```